# Integral of a sum under condition

Tags: integration, summation, actuarial-science

I'm struggling with the following integral, would anyone have an idea on how to approach it? I solved it for N = 2 but the generalization to any positive integer is more difficult.

$$\int_{(\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_N) \in [0,1]^N \\ \sum_{i=1}^N \omega_i = 1} \sum_{i=1}^N \min{ (\omega_i\cdot E, L_i)}$$

with:

-$E \geqslant 0$

-$\forall i, L_i >0$

-$N > 1$, strictly positive integer

Solution for N = 2:

I found the following for N = 2:

|  | $E < L_2$ | $E > L_2$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $E< L_1$ | $E$ | $\frac{E}{2} + L_2 - \frac{L_2^2}{2E}$ |
| $E > L_1$ | $\frac{E}{2} + L_1 - \frac{L_1^2}{2E}$ | $L_1 + L_2 - \frac{L_1^2 + L_2^2}{2E}$ |

after having computed $\int_0^1 (\min{(\alpha E, L_1)} + \min{((1 -\alpha) E, L_2)} )\,d\alpha $

What is a bit frustating is to not have a nice formula, even for N=2 (this may exist but I haven't found it).

I have a master's degree in applied mathematics but I'm not that young anymore and a bit rusty so I would really appreciate the help of a fresh mind. (But I accept contributions from older persons ;) ).

Kind regards

Comment: How does this relate to actuarial science?  (Long ago, I was an actuary, so I'm curious.)

Comment: It will probably be in terms of $E$ and $M_i=\min(L_i/E,1).$

Comment: @saulspatz This is the calculation of a loss (sum of several loss components) when the various loss components $\omega_i E$ are reinsured and limited by a limit $L_i$ :)

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, not an answer, but my MathJax isn't good enough to type it in a comment box.  For $i=1,2$, let $$
f_i=\begin{cases} \frac E2,&E\leq L_i\\
L_i-\frac{L_i^2}{2E},&E>L_i
 \end{cases}$$

Then when $N=2$, your answer equals $$\sum_{i=1}^2f_i$$

I would try to generalize this approach.  See if you can evaluate the integral for a single summand.

Comment: If you let $M_i=\min(L_i/E,1)$ this can be written without case: $$f_i=E\left(M_i-\frac{M_i^2}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

First, a rewriting of your formula to show the power of using my $M_i.$

Letting $M_i=\min(L_i/E,1)$ your table becomes:

|  | $M_2=1$ | $M_2<1$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $M_1=1$ | $E$ | $E\left(\frac{1}{2} + M_2 - \frac{M_2^2}{2}\right)$ |
| $M_1<1$ | $E\left(\frac{1}{2} + M_1 - \frac{M_1^2}{2}\right)$ | $E\left(M_1 + M_2 - \frac{M_1^2 + M_2^2}{2}\right)$ |

So in all cases you get one formula which works for all $M_i,$ with no cases:

$$E\left(M_1 + M_2 - \frac{M_1^2 + M_2^2}{2}\right)$$

---

Now, let us compute:

$$E\int_{(\omega_j)\in[0,1]^N\,\sum \omega_1=1} \min(\omega_i,M_i)$$

This can be rewritten:

$$\int_{t\in[0,M_i]}t\int_{(x_j)\in[0,1-t]^{N-1}\,\sum x_j =1-T}1\\+\int_{t\in [M_i,1]} M_i \int_{(x_j)\in[0,1-t]^{N-1}\,\sum x_j =1-t}1$$

Now $$\int_{(x_j)\in[0,1-t]^{N-1}\,\sum x_j =1-t}1=\frac{(1-t)^{N-2}}{(N-2)!}$$

So we get:

$$\frac{E}{(N-2)!}\left(\int_0^{M_i}t(1-t)^{N-2}\,dt+M_i\int_ {M_i}^1 (1-t)^{N-2}\right)\,dt$$

Writing $$t(1-t)^{N-2}=(1-t)^{N-2}-(1-t)^{N-1}$$

You get: $$\frac{E}{(N-2)!}\left(\left(\frac1N(1-t)^N-\frac1{N-1}(1-t)^{N-1}\right)\bigg \vert_0^{M_i}
-\frac{M_{i}}{N-1}(1-t)^{N-1}\bigg\vert_{M_i}^1\right)$$

That’s a bit messy, but you get:

$$\frac{E}{(N-2)!}\left(\frac{(1-M_i)^N}{N}-\frac{(1-M_i)^{N-1}}{N-1}+\frac{1}{N(N-1)} +M_i(1-M_i)^{N-1}\right)\\
=\frac{E(1-M_i)^{N-1}}{N!}\left((N-1)^2M_i-1\right)+\frac{E}{N!}$$

So your integral is:

$$\frac{E}{(N-1)!}+\frac{E}{N!}\sum_i (1-M_i)^{N-1}((N-1)^2M_i-1)$$

When $N=2$ this gives:

$$E+\frac E2\sum_i(-1+2M_i-M_i^2)=E\left(M_1+M_2-\frac{M_1^2+M_2^2}{2}\right)$$

When $N=3$ you get:

$$\frac E2+\frac{E}{6}\sum_i (1-M_i)^2(4M_i-1)\\=\frac E6\sum_i\left(4M_i^3-9M_i^2+6M_i\right)$$

—-

You can write $$(N-1)^2M_i-1=N(N-2)-(N-1)^2(1-M_i).$$ That lets you write everything as polynomials of $K_i=1-M_i.$

$$\frac E{(N-1)!}+\frac E{N!}\sum_i \left(N(N-2)K_i^{N-1}-(N-1)^2 K_i^N\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, true the $M$ it seems interesting. I'll investigate this :)

Comment: @Seepher finished the question. Messy, but not as messy as I guessed.

Comment: Basically the $M$ work as if ensuring that $L_i\leq E.$ When they are strictly greater, the value has no effect on the integral versus when $L_i=E.$, But we get a simple continuous function of the $L_i$ if we ensure the $L_i$ are no bigger than $E,$ so we don’t have to break out into cases.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to sense check the result. Intuitively, I would expect the coefficient in front of $M_i$ to be 1. Indeed, I would expect the calculated quantity to have a limit of $\sum_i L_i$ when $E \to +\infty$. This works for $N=2$ but the formula applied to $N=3$ you provided above does not verify my intuition (it's equivalent to $\frac{3(L_1 + L_2 + L_3)}{2}$ when $E \to +\infty$).

Comment: After a check, I believe this is only a typo for $N=3$, as it should be $\frac{E}{i} \sum_i (4M_i^3 - 9M_i^2+6M_i)$ which verify asymptotically the equality with $\sum_i L_i$.

Comment: PS: I meant $\frac{E}{6}$ and not $\frac{E}{i}$ in the post above.

Comment: You are correct. I lazily let Wolfram do the algebra for me, then failed when copying over. Fixed. @Seepher